# Word to describe the list of people that I have a crush, love, and lust

Tags: single-word-requests

You love a girl. You also have a crush on a girl who works in your office. You also have a lust on a neighborhood girl. What word would you use to describe all of them? Your "Romances"?

I'm looking for the word (noun, plural) to describe the list of people that I have a crush, love, and lust. I'm looking for one single word if possible.

I think I need a word like heartthrobs. But heartthrobs seems to be used for only for men. I need a similar word which can be used for both men and women.

So far, the best words I got are sweethearts and romances. But looking for a better more accurate word.

Still, if you're not sure what I'm asking Read this. If I have borrowed money, a property, a thing from the list of people, I can use the word "lenders" to describe them, right? So,  if I a have crush on a list of people. On each of them, I have a different type of crushes like love, lust, infatuation, etc. Which single word I can use to describe them?

Comment: What about "emotions"? More specifically, how about "amorousness"? See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/amorous

Comment: All of my(his/her) "romantic interests" would get the point across.

Comment: Are you looking for a word to categorize the words "love," "lust," and "crush" themselves, or the objects of the "love," etc.? Rhetorician's suggestion is the first, while Tom22's is the second.

Comment: I'm looking for the word to describe the list of people that I have a crush, love, and lust. I'm looking for one single word if possible.

Comment: @vanderpn Looks like amorous is used to describe mainly illicit love. I don't want that. Because Love, Lust and Crush can be non-illicit as well.

Comment: Cross posted: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124645/a-common-word-or-group-or-description-of-all-the-following-love-lust-crush-i

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the adjective you're looking for is

**amorous**

as in "of, or related to" all kinds of love matters.

amorous affairs, amorous matters, amorous feelings, amorous emotions

Comment: Thanks, "amorous affairs" looks good. Is it possible to come up with a single word to descript "amorous affairs"? What is the plural of amorous?

Comment: Looks like amorous is used to describe mainly illicit love. I don't want that. Because Love, Lust and Crush can be non-illicit as well.

Comment: //Looks like amorous is used to describe mainly illicit love// No, it isn't.

Comment: okay, is it okay if I use "my amorous list" to describe the list of people I have crushes (crush, love, lust) on?

Comment: @user43286: Of course. It's a classic, in fact. Google for "The first who appeared on this amorous list."

Answer (score 1):

**Attraction**

> a person or thing that draws, attracts, allures, or entices ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/attraction))

And from the [Psychology Dictionary](http://psychologydictionary.org/attraction/):

> n. 1. in social psychology, the natural feeling of being drawn to other individuals and desiring their company.
>
> 2. in environmental psychology, a quality that affects the proximity of relationships - usually reflecting such factors as their liking for each other.

If you use it in a sentence, you can readily substitute the words "love", "lust", "crush", or "infatuation" (with some minor adjustments):

> John's *attraction* to his wife had grown beyond the *attraction* he had when they first met. He was *attracted* to her before then but he already had a deep *attraction* to another who he had just met.

becomes

> John's *love* of his wife had grown beyond the *lust* he had when they first met. He was *infatuated* with her before then but he already had a deep *crush* on another who he had just met.

Comment: Attraction is too generic. Any other better word?

Comment: I think I need a word like heartthrobs. But heartthrobs seems to be used for only for men. I need to similar word which can be used for both men and women.

Comment: I looking for a noun, especially plural word to describe the list of people that I have a crush, love, and lust.

Comment: If you are not already familiar with the word in this context, you might think so. But it is routinely used for this very purpose, as the Psychology Dictionary attests to

Answer (score 0):

> **amatory**  or **amatorial** (adj).  Also called: **amatorian** or **amatorious**
>
> **Of, relating to, or expressive of love, especially romantic love:**
>
> *an amatory mood; an amatory embrace.*
>
> (***[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/amatory)***)

Answer (score 0):

There is the old-fashioned term ***inamorata***, which originally meant

> A female lover, mistress, sweetheart. ("inamorata, n." OED Online. Oxford University Press, March 2017.)

You could think of this as referring to anyone with whom you are [*enamored*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enamour). From Oxford Dictionaries:

> VERB (**be enamoured of/with/by**)
>   1. Be filled with love for.
>   1.1 Have a liking or admiration for.

The verb fairly neatly covers all of your categories; unfortunately, in modern usage the noun has acquired some connotations of illicitness. However, it is still used occasionally for unrequited (and therefore entirely licit) crushes:

> I'm not thinking about stalkers, creeps who make the women uncomfortable or, God help us, attack them, but about a person with a normal unhealthy and insane **platonic crush** on someone unattainable. . . . I've talked to several men who contrived to meet their broadcasting **inamorata**, and they fall into two camps: those who find them down to earth and unpretentious and then go back to watching them on the tube with a deeper sense of connection, and those who, as the novelist Michael Griffith put it, find them as "dumb as a box of hair." ([Andrew Hudgins, "Love in a Box", *The American Scholar*, vol. 73, no. 4, Sept. 2004, pp. 35-39.](https://books.google.com/books?id=3b3x6gMUmvcC&q=inamorata%20%22crush%20on%22&dq=inamorata%20%22crush%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgssXP9JPTAhWK4yYKHRaECUo4ChDoAQgwMAQ) Actual article is paywalled, so link is to snippet view.)

Note that this term applies specifically to female objects of affection; it was originally an Italian borrowing, and retains the -a/-o gender distinction.

Answer (score -2):

Your heartthrobs, perhaps. Or objects of your affections.

Comment: Oh! Nice. But heartthrobs can be used for non-celebrities? Dictionary meaning says "a man, typically a celebrity, whose good looks excite immature romantic feelings in women"

Comment: Looks like Heartthrobs is used for only men. Is there any other word to mean both men and women crush, love and lust?